# Drill can query on open HDFS directories?

Tags: hive, apache-drill

I am successfully query HIVE and HBase tables by using Drill.In my usecase i am getting data from storm into HDFS directory,for that directory i am creating Hive structure and querying that data by using Hive and Drill.Whenever storm is writing data into that directory(means directory is opened and writing data into hdfs) then drill is not able to query that hive table,it is giving error as,

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Cannot obtain block length for LocatedBlock{BP-517438351-192.168.1.136-1475035616867:blk_1073793923_53182; getBlockSize()=0; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[127.0.0.1:50010]; storageIDs=[DS-be58a5f4-58d9-4c3c-8138-ce18ffa10ef8]; storageTypes=[DISK]}
```

if we are stop writing then drill is able to query that hive tables.In both cases hive is working properly.I am not able to find the cause.

Anybody can you please tell me,Drill can query opened HDFS files or directories or not?I tried alot but not getting anything about that.

Comment: anybody have any idea please share me.................

Comment: how to query that streaming HDFS directory using drill.

Answer (score 0):

Technically any file system (ext2, ext3, or hdfs) should be consistent to read/ write. When you are writing data to directory, file system is set to writing mode by one process and can not give read access to another process. Even though you force to read data, the process in reading gets inconsistent data.
This is the reason, any file/ directory, when it is in writing mode may not get reading access. In my opinion, in hdfs you may not execute read query when another process is writing to same file.

Comment: In your error, it is very clear that hdfs is not giving access to that memory block for apache drill. Try the same query, when storm stop writing data.

Comment: so i am not able to use both at a time in  my usecase.

Comment: I am not an expert in apache drill, but as per my understanding you may not use apache drill on opened files ...

Comment: What i did for this problem is I created two directories in hdfs,one is for reading purpose and another one is for writing purpose.I made sync between these two directories by using hadoop's distcp command.I am running this command using crontab.so in drill i am able to read.I solved this problem like this.But i don't know whether it is better approach or not also.If anybody have any idea please share me any other way is possible or this way is better way.